# CSS page border not working in print preview page

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want set page border to my html printable page. When we see in browser view border working correctly. The main problem with checking print preview page only.

```
@media print {
        @page {  
            size:200mm 297mm; 
            margin: 0.5mm;
        } 

        body {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 3mm;
        }
    }
```

I have tried the `@media print` code. Anyone help me to achieve this.

```css
table {position:relative;width: 100%;}
 .kprj-left {width: 160px;position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 270px;}
 .kprj-right {max-width: 100px;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 90px;}
 body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204);  
  margin:10px auto;
 }
 p {
  font-size:17px;
 }
 @media screen {
 
  body {
   width: 210mm;
   /*height:297mm;*/
   margin: 20px auto;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .tablebr {
   box-shadow: 0 7px 14px 0 rgba(50,50,93,0.10), 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
  }
  @page {  
   size:210mm 297mm;  
   margin:0.5in;
  } 
  .bg-blackwh {background:#000;color:#fff;}
 }
 @media print {
  @page {  
   size:200mm 297mm; 
  } 
    body {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 3mm;
  }
  .page-break { 
        height:2px; 
        border-top:1px solid #999; 
        margin-bottom:13px;
        page-break-after: always;  
    }
  .setbr {
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  body,html {
   box-shadow: 0;
   width:100%;
   max-width:100%; 
   position: relative;
  }
  
  table {
   width:100%;
   max-width:100%;
   box-shadow: none;
   border:0;
  }
  .bg-blackwh {font-size:15px;}
 }
```

```html
<table style="position:relative;background-color:#fff;padding:60px;" class="">
  <tbody>
        <thead>   
   <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
     <img src="http://orderonline.my/email/kprj-right.png" alt="kprj-right" style="max-width: 100px;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 90px;" class="kprj-left">
    </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <img alt="kprj-logo" src="http://orderonline.my/email/kprj-logo.png" style="display: block;border: 0;line-height: 100%;max-width: 280px;margin: 0 auto;">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:30px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <h3 style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-size: 32px;font-weight: 300;letter-spacing: 1px;">PERAKUAN PENDAFTARAN</h3>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:30px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">No Pendaftaran</p>
                    <p style="padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;"><strong>K-BG70377</strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:30px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">Adalah disahkan
                        <br>Syarikat/Firma berikut telah didaftarkan sebagai:-</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:40px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-style: italic;text-decoration: underline;font-size: 22px;"><strong>KONTRAKTOR</strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">dengan KUMPULAN PRASARANA RAKYAT JOHOR SDN BHD dan/atau anak-anak syarikatnya dengan tertakluk kepada terma dan syarat yang ditetapkan</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">Tempoh sahlaku pendaftaran ini bermula dari</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;"><strong>10hb APRIL 2018</strong> hingga <strong>09hb APRIL 2020</strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:40px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table style="max-width:400px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <p style="line-height: 30px;margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-size: 18px;">Nama</p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;">:</td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;line-height: 30px;">
                                <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;"><strong>VECTOR INFOTECH SDN. BHD.</strong></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <p style="line-height: 30px;margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-size: 18px;">Alamat</p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;">:</td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;"><strong>NO. 37, JALAN 4/93,</strong></p>
                                <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;"><strong>TAMAN MIHARJA,</strong></p>
                                <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;"><strong>OFF JALAN LOKE YEW,</strong></p>
                                <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;line-height: 30px;font-size: 18px;"><strong>55200 KUALA LUMPUR.</strong></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:80px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="padding: 0 0 0;width: 350px;border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;letter-spacing: 0px;margin: 0 auto;"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
                    <p style="padding: 0 0 0;margin:0 0 0;font-style:italic;"><strong>(HAJI MOHD NOORAZAM B. DATO&#39; OSMAN)</strong></p>
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">Ketua Pengarah Eksekutif</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;"></td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
                <td>
     <img src="http://orderonline.my/email/kprj-left.png" alt="kprj-left" class="kprj-left" style="width: 160px;position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 270px;">
    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;" colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;font-style:italic;font-size:13px;">Nota:</p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;">
                                <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;font-style:italic;font-size:13px;">Pembaharuan pendaftaran perlu dibuat selewat-lewatnya satu (1) bulan sebelum tamat sahlaku pendaftaran.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="height:10px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align:top;" colspan="2">
                                <p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;color:#fff;background:#000;" class="bg-blackwh">G-07 & G-08 Blok 4 Danga Bay, Jalan Skudai, 80200 Johor Bahru, Johor Darul Takzim. Tel: 07-2358377; Fax: 07-2359377</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

something error in your css code because print css works good i have check my side just find out css error within your css style.

```css
body{border: 1px solid #000}
 @media print {
        @page {  
            size:200mm 297mm; 
            margin: 0.5mm;
        } 

        body {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 3mm;
        }
    }
```

```html
<table style="position:relative;background-color:#fff;padding:60px;" class="">
<tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
<p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">No Pendaftaran</p>
<p style="padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;font-style: italic;"><strong>K-BG70377</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:30px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
<p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">Adalah disahkan
<br>Syarikat/Firma berikut telah didaftarkan sebagai:-</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:40px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
<p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-style: italic;text-decoration: underline;font-size: 22px;"><strong>KONTRAKTOR</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:20px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
<p style="margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0;font-weight: 300;">dengan KUMPULAN PRASARANA RAKYAT JOHOR SDN BHD dan/atau anak-anak syarikatnya dengan tertakluk kepada terma dan syarat yang ditetapkan</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I know something error in my code . for that only I have raised the question.